# DRBD - How to initialize primary without any secondary server available?

Tags: drbd

Here is the normal way to initialize the drbd partition:

ON BOTH SERVERS

```
drbdadm create-md r0
drbdadm up r0
```

Both servers should be now connected, check with

ONLY ON PRIMARY

```
drbdadm -- --overwrite-data-of-peer primary r0
cat /proc/drbd
```

AFTER BOTH SERVERS UP-TO-DATE - ON PRIMARY

```
mkfs –t ext4 –b 4096 /dev/drbd0
```

I now tried to prepare a primary without secondary available (e.g. customer
wants a single server system and probably later wants to add a hot-standby
server)

```
drbdadm create-md r0
drbdadm up r0
drbdadm primary r0
```

I got the error:

> 0: State change failed: (-2) Need access to UpToDate data

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

Force the node you wish to become Primary to Primary.

```
# drbdadm create-md r0
# drbdadm up r0
# drbdadm primary r0 --force
```